# Does foreach automatically call Dispose?

Tags: c#, foreach, idisposable

In C#, Does foreach automatically call Dispose on any object implementing IDisposable?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754(v=vs.71).aspx seems to indicate that it does:

*Otherwise, the collection expression is of a type that implements System.IEnumerable, and the expansion of the foreach statement is:
Copy

```
IEnumerator enumerator = 
        ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)(collection)).GetEnumerator();
try {
   while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      ElementType element = (ElementType)enumerator.Current;
      statement;
   }
}
finally {
   IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
   if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, foreach will call Dispose() on the enumerator if it implements IDisposable.

Comment: In case it is confusing, it looks like it calls dispose on the enumerator itself, not the items in the enumeration.  If it called it on each item, that would probably break a lot of scenarios, and be very hard to make exception safe :)

Comment: The `foreach` method will only perform a run-time check on the object returned from `GetEnumerator` to see whether it implements `IDisposable` if the return type of that method is an interface.  Otherwise, the compiler will decide at compile-time whether or not `Dispose` will be called.  In particular, if the return-type is an inheritable class which does not implement `IDisposable`, the returned object will not be disposed *even if it does implement `IDisposable`*.

Comment: @supercat, can you please explaing further, for the benefit of my understanding (and maybe others, too ;-). All i can gather from the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is that when  `E enumerator` is a `final class` and does _not_ implmenent `IDisposable` that then the implementation can be optimized and "In this case, the implementation can safely optimize away the entire finally clause." (= no call to `.Dispose()`). But i can't see any possibility where `E enumerator` does indeed implement `IDisposable` but `.Dispose()` is not getting called.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit: I think I misspoke above.  I mostly use VB.NET, which is similar to C# in many ways, and its `For Each` behaves as described.

Comment: For those looking for the up to date documentation about this behaviour: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators#deeper-dive-into-foreach

Answer (score 19):

This question / answer is poorly worded.

It is not clear if the question asked is:

Q: "Does foreach dispose objects returned by the enumerator before moving to the next?"

A: The answer is of course, NO. It does nothing except provide a convenient way to run some code once for each object in an enumeration.

Or whether it means:

Q: "Under the hood, foreach uses an enumerable object. Does this get disposed after the call to foreach, even if there's an exception in the iterator block?"

A: The answer is (still fairly obviously) YES! Since the syntax does not provide you access to the enumerator, it has the responsibility to dispose it.

The answer to the second question is where the confusion arises, since people have heard that foreach expands to a while block with a try/finally block. The purpose of that finally is to ensure that the enumerator is disposed if it implements IDisposable.

In case you need to see it for yourself: [See it in action here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Hope this helps clarify! ;)

Comment: By "foreach uses an enumerable object" you meant "foreach uses an enumerator given by the enumerable collection".

Comment: I've learned the hard way that I still have to Dispose the collection (enumerable) :(