# .Net WMI classes - which ones do I have to dispose?

Tags: c#, linq, wmi, idisposable

If I am using a [`ManagementObjectSearcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx), I can easily wrap it in a `using` block:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    // ...
}
```

It is also easy to dispose [the collection returned from the searcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectcollection.aspx), due to the fact that [`foreach` automatically calls dispose on the enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982396/does-foreach-automatically-call-dispose):

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    foreach(ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But `ManagementObject` also implements `IDisposable`:

```
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    foreach(ManagementObject mo in searcher.Get())
    {
        // ...

        mo.Dispose(); // ?
    }
}
```

- Do I have to dispose each `ManagementObject` instance returned in this scenario?
- If I do, how do I make it exception safe?
- Is there a way I can still use Linq in this scenario (and still properly call `Dispose`)?  Especially with constructions like `searcher.Get().First()`?

**Edit**: A few more related questions:

- Do I also have to call `Dispose` on the search result collection?
- How about the searcher?

They both also implement their own `IDisposable` method, though it seems like the searcher only inherits the `Dispose` implementation from `Component`; it doesn't add its own dispose behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ManagementObject` inherits from `System.ComponentModel.Component` and [you should call `Dispose` explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=VS.100).aspx) for all inherited from `Component` objects.
You can use `LINQ` methods with your own predicates which invokes `Dispose` itself:

```
var first = searcher.Get().First(x =>
                {
                    bool result = Satisfy(x);

                    if (!result)
                    {
                        x.Dispose();
                    }

                    return result;
                });
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
ManagementObject first = null;

foreach (var element in searcher.Get())
{
    if (Satisfy(element))
    {
        first = element;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        element.Dispose();    
    }
}

if (first == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No match");
}
```

Where `Satisfy` is your own method.

Comment: Sorry to bloat my question after you've answered it.  Please see my edits.  You mention the verbiage at the bottom that says you should always call `Dispose` on classes derived from `Component`.  However, is there any reason for this for a class that doesn't add any of its own `Dispose` implementation?  I see from Reflector that there is some interesting stuff in the guts of `Dispose` on `Component`, but it seems like it would only apply if I used it in some sort of "site" context.  I can't tell if that applies in this case...

Comment: Checked it, and `Site` seems to be null.  I'm not binding to on-Dispose events, so it really seems like it wouldn't do anything in this case.  But I'd appreciate your two cents.

Comment: I think that the following framework developers recommendations is a good practice. Really, you shouldn't use reflector or anything else to make any suppositions or assumptions about how exactly this version of code works. In MSDN Microsoft writes that you have to call `Dispose` for every object which inherited from `Component`. If you don't you may get problems in some complicated use-case or in further versions of framework. Ignoring the specifications is the first thing causes application fails in new version of OS or framework.

Comment: Great point.  I will wrap it all in extension methods, anyhow :)