# why these objects are not getting disposed

Tags: c#, foreach, idisposable

My understanding is that if an object that implements `IDisposable` pattern is called within a foreach loop, its got disposed automatically without need to use it in a using or calling `Dispose` method explicitly. I have following code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (Employee e = new Employee() { Name = "John" }) ;
        {

        }

        foreach (var e in GetEmployees())
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
    }

    static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee() { Name = "Peter" };
        Employee emp2 = new Employee() { Name = "Smith" };
        List<Employee> emps = new List<Employee>();
        emps.Add(emp);
        emps.Add(emp2);
        return emps;
    }
}

class Employee : IDisposable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("disposing " + Name);
    }
}
```

I don't see `Dispose` is called for objects returned by `GetEmployees` method. Does it mean I need to call `Dispose` within foreach loop?

Comment: You're not calling Dispose. So Dispose isn't getting called.

Comment: In a word, yes.  `foreach` does not expect the items it iterates over to be disposable and therefore can not and does not dispose of them.

Comment: _"My understanding is that if an object that implements IDisposable pattern is called within a foreach loop, its got disposed automatically without need to use it in a using or calling Dispose method explicitly"_ 
Your understanding is wrong. Replace the "without need to" with "if you" and you're right.

Comment: `foreach` doesn't do the `Dispose`, `using` does.

Comment: @johnsmith `foreach` really calls `Dispose` but only on the `IEnumerator`-like object that is used to enumerate over the collection - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982396/does-foreach-automatically-call-dispose

Comment: Why do you need to dispose employees at all? I think you are misunderstanding disposing. Use it only if your class uses [unmanaged resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197/what-exactly-are-unmanaged-resources).

Comment: I am thinking you are getting Dispose, Garbage Collection and Scoping mixed up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach` doesn't call the `Dispose` method, only `using` does. `using` directive is just a sugar for:

```
try {
    // Initialize
}
finally {
    // Dispose
}
```

And yes, you have to write `Dispose` call by youself, like this:

```
foreach (var e in GetEmployees())
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
    e.Dispose();
}
```

or

```
foreach (var e in GetEmployees())
{
    using (e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
    }
}
```

Consider [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) from MSDN for better understanding way the `Disposing` works in .NET:

**Simple use-case**:

```
public class DisposableResourceHolder : IDisposable {

    private SafeHandle resource; // handle to a resource

    public DisposableResourceHolder(){
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
        if (disposing){
            if (resource!= null) resource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Complex use-case with finalizible types:

```
public class ComplexResourceHolder : IDisposable {

    private IntPtr buffer; // unmanaged memory buffer
    private SafeHandle resource; // disposable handle to a resource

    public ComplexResourceHolder(){
        this.buffer = ... // allocates memory
        this.resource = ... // allocates the resource
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
            ReleaseBuffer(buffer); // release unmanaged memory
        if (disposing){ // release other disposable objects
            if (resource!= null) resource.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ~ ComplexResourceHolder(){
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

*Update*: As in comments noted, I think that you are mixing up the [`Garbage Collection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx) and [`Disposing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx). `Disposing` is used for freeing up the unmanaged resources outside the .NET Framework in your application. `Garbage Collection` is done automatically and you should not force it until you have completely understanding why do you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either call Dispose() manually, or use the `using()` statement

Comment: how can i call using within that foreach loop?

Comment: @johnsmith `using(e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Name); }`

Comment: @johnsmith You almost certainly shouldn't be doing that. The point of `IDisposable`/`using` is that it *always* gets cleaned up appropriately. Putting your `using` inside the loop means that if any iteration of the loop throws an exception, only that item gets disposed, the remaining items won't.

Comment: @hvd Can you clarify what I shouldn't be doing? Calling Dispose on object in a loop or use of using in a loop?

Comment: @johnsmith `GetEmployees()` returns a number of disposable objects, so the `Dispose()` should be somewhere where it is guaranteed to be called if `GetEmployees()` returns normally. I think the best way here would be `var employees = GetEmployees(); try { foreach (var employee in employees) { ... } } finally { foreach (var employee in employees) { if (employee != null) employee.Dispose(); } } }` It's still in a loop, and it's not inherently a problem that it's in a loop, the problem was that it wasn't guaranteed to get called in all cases where you might want it to get called.

Comment: @johnsmith Even better would be to not return `List<Employee>` in the first place. A `DisposableList<T> where T : IDisposable` that handles the disposing of its elements internally means the caller can simply do: `using (var employees = GetEmployees()) foreach (var employee in employees) { ... }`.