# Can I call Dispose for copy of Enumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

I have collection of enumerators:

```
var collections = new List<List<object>>();
var enumerators = collections.Select(с => c.GetEnumerator());
```

and try to dispose them:

```
foreach(var enumerator in enumerators)
{
    enumerator.Dispose();
}
```

But enumerator is a struct. So when I call `enumerator.Dispose()`, CLR create copy of enumerator and call `Dispose()` for copy.

Is it correct way to dispose enumerator?

**UPDATE**: enumerators is IEnumerable so it is not struct and all should work well

Comment: Why are you trying to dispose a `List`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If a class does not implement IDisposable, then there is no Dispose() method to call.  structs, by definition, do not implement any interface.

Comment: when dispose is not implemented in .Net libraries means you dont have to dispose.

Comment: 1. Enumerator is not a struct.
2. foreach will call Dispose automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982396/does-foreach-automatically-call-dispose

Answer (score 2):

The `List<T>.Enumerator` struct does absolutely nothing in its `Dispose` method, it's an empty method as you can [see in the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646)

There's no need to dispose your collection, let the GC do it's thing once you're done.

If you created a custom collection where you actually allocate resources that need to be disposed, `foreach` will call dispose for you once you're done iterating.

Comment: Actually, I have other collection. I gave List as an example. But now I understand that answer depend on Enumerator implementation.

Comment: While it can be correct for some implementations, in general it is wrong to think that GC will call Dispose when things are done.

Comment: @arbiter I did not say the GC will call dispose and that wasn't what I meant, at all. I was referring to the fact that `List<T>` does nothing in its dispose and theres no reason to do so, simply let the GC collect it when you're done using it.