# Real ManagementObject foreach loop resource leak or false positive?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, coverity

I'm working with ManagementObjects and foreach loops in C#. Coverity is claiming that there is a leak in code like this:

```
ObjectQuery myQuery = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer");
using (ManagementObjectSearcher mySearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(myQuery))
{
    // alloc_fn: A new resource is returned from allocation method Current.get
    // var_assign: Assigning: mo = resource returned from mo$iterator.Current
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mySearcher.Get())
    {
        foreach (PropertyData p in mo.Properties)
        {
            // do stuff, maybe return a string
        }
    }
}
// leaked_resource: Returning without closing mo leaks the resource that it refers to
return "";
```

Is this a real leak or a false positive?

Is the using block even needed here (it was my initial attempt at avoiding a leak)?

My thinking is that this is a managed collection that implements IDisposable and the caller shouldn't be responsible for destroying it. I've seen the following code suggested before, but it seems like it's heading down the wrong path with more using blocks:

```
...
    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mySearcher.Get()) using(mo)
...
```

Comment: Well, pray tell, did it stop complaining when you fixed your code?

Comment: @HansPassant The above code is what Coverity is complaining about. I don't think there is actually a leak there, but I'm not sure. The MSDN example I found doesn't have any using blocks ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186146(VS.80).aspx)). I'm inclined to change the code to more closely resemble that example, but want to do my homework on the issue. Right now I have about a 48hr delay before I can get updated Coverity results for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ManagementObject` is disposable and it is not being disposed in that code. That's what the warning is about. It's a true positive.

The collection class (`mySearcher.Get()`) also is not being disposed but it should be. Coverity should warn about it.

I have done very little WMI so far but it seems almost everything needs to be disposed. A nasty API. Win32 shines through.

If this is a throw away program I'd simply not worry about any of it. Otherwise, you probably need to dispose.

Comment: It's my understanding that mySearcher.Get() returns a ManagementObjectCollection that inherits from ICollection, IEnumerable, and IDisposable. Based on this SO post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982396/does-foreach-automatically-call-dispose) and my research, the foreach should be disposing of the ManagementObjectCollection already, right?

Comment: foreach disposes the enumerator, not the enumerable. If that was the case looping over anything would kill it!

Comment: So each ManagementObject is being newed up somewhere in the iterator and requires an explicit call to Dispose (or a wrapping in a using block)?

Comment: Yes. According to Reflector it does not seem to be bound to the collection you got it from.