# When is Dispose() of a class implementing IEnumerator<T> called automatically by Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, idisposable, ienumerator

I'm studying `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`.

I wrote the code referring to [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-6.0#examples).

Here's a part of the example code in the link that uses it:

```cs
var stringsFound =
    from line in new StreamReaderEnumerable(@"C:\temp\tempFile.txt")
    where line.Contains("string to search for")
    select line;

Console.WriteLine($"Found : {stringsFound.Count()}");
```

I have a question for you here.

`StreamReaderEnumerator` is created automatically by the system, so when is `StreamReaderEnumerator`'s `Dispose()` called?

Comment: "I want to explicitly call Dispose() here." Um... ***Why?***

Comment: Isn't `StreamReaderEnumerable` essentially recreating `File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\tempFile.txt")`?

Comment: @Sweeper Because I've learned that it's better to explicitly Dispose() than to be called by the Finalizer. Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: After calling `.ToList()` on `stringsFound`, it hits `Dispose()` (long before it will ever hit `~StreamReaderEnumerable()`), which is expected. Likewise with calling `stringsFound.Count();`. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: You can see for yourself from the code that `StreamReaderEnumerable` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, so of course you can't dispose it. It is `StringReaderEnumerator` that implements `IDisposable` and you never use that class directly, so there's nothing for you to dispose. You are implicitly creating an `IEnumerator` every time you use a `foreach` loop or execute a LINQ query. The system will handle disposal in those cases because the system is creating the disposable object.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I don't know why `Dispose()` occurs on `stringsFound`. Do you know when it happens?

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I meant `StreamReaderEnumerator` gets disposed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982396/does-foreach-automatically-call-dispose) for why it happens, and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/april/essential-net-understanding-csharp-foreach-internals-and-custom-iterators-with-yield) MSDN Magazine issue.

Comment: As you can see from the spec https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#1295-the-foreach-statement a `foreach` statement implies a `Dispose`. And all Linq functions are designed the same way as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your code creates any enumerators that *you* are responsible for disposing of. LINQ operators like `Count` are designed so that they create and dispose the enumerators internally, so you don't have to worry about it at all.

You can see the reference source for `Count` [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs,32), and you'll find the snippet:

```
int count = 0;
using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
{
    checked
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

return count;
```

The `using` statement already disposes the enumerator for you - `Dispose` *is* called, before `Count` even returns. There's nothing for you to do.

Of course, if you are consuming `stringsFound` by getting its enumerator (though it's very rare that you'd need to do it this way), you *do* need to remember to dispose it.

```
var stringsFoundEnumerator = stringsFound.GetEnumerator();
//  ^^^^^^ remember to dispose this!
```

Side note: `foreach` loops translates to `while` loops wrapped by a `using` statement, so you don't need to worry about disposing the enumerator if you are iterating over `stringsFound` with a `foreach` loop either. :D

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation, it helped me to understand more deeply :)