# Building SQL "where in" statement from list of strings in one line?

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have a List(Of String) which corresponds to "types" on our database table.

We are using the DB2 ADO.NET provider and my final query needs to look something like this:

```
select * from table where type in (@type1, @type2, @type3, @type4)
```

In the past, I've built the list of query parameters / host variables using a ForEach loop, but I would really like to figure out a way to build them in one line. Of course, I can join all of the strings, but adding the "@" and the incrementing digit is giving me headaches.

Anyone have any ideas  on how to do this?

Comment: in .net 4 there is the String.Concat method but getting the index of the item in the iEnumerable is a pain and not a one liner.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290603/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-ienumerable  I'd be interested in the solution for this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Won't something like this work?

```
var inList = "(" + string.Join(", ", typeList.Select(t => "@" + t)) + ")";
```

#### Edit

Based on your comment, how about this?

```
var inList = "(" + 
    string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1, argCount).Select(i +> "@type" + i)) +
    ")";
```

Comment: I've have had a similar issue in the past and building these up by hand in a pain. I really like the elegence of the linq method!

Comment: Good ol' LINQ-to-String to the rescue. :)

Comment: Well, I actually need the parameters to literally be @type1, @type2, etc. With the numbers and all. I'm just trying to create a parameter for each type and I'll fill each parameter with the actual values of the types before executing the query.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I generally do this

```
string.Join(",", items.Select(i => $"'{i}'");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string dbCommand = 
    string.Format("select * from table where type in ({0})", string.Join(",", typeList.Select(p => "@" + p));
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the list using as `string.Join(",", listType.ToArray())`

```
    string types = string.Join(",", listType.ToArray());

    Select * from table where type in (types)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to use :

```
"'" + string.Join("','", myListOfNames) + "'")
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL/ADO.NET does not support arrays.  So you really have to build the SQL by hand.

SQL 2008 does support a Table parameter, but it seems a lot of overhead.  See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html for more details.