# SQL find rows with key specified in list, C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to make a sql query in C# that finds all rows with a key that is specified in a list. Can I do this with one query? I suppose that is much more efficent than my solution which finds one item at the time inside a for loop, se below:

```
foreach (int i in list)
{
    string Q = "... where pk = " + i.ToString();
    using (SqlCommand CM = new SqlCommand(Q, C))
    {
         using (SqlDataReader R = CM.ExecuteReader())
         {
              while (R.Read())
              {
                  ...
              }
          }
     }
}
```

list contains different in values.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the `IN` SQL keyword. [Building SQL “where in” statement from list of strings in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272214/building-sql-where-in-statement-from-list-of-strings-in-one-line) for example. Obligatory "use prepared statements instead of manually crafting SQL strings".

Comment: Can't u send the list as a parameter using Table valued parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
string Q = "... where pk = " + i.ToString();
```

with

```
string Q = "... where pk IN ('" + string.Join("','", list)+"')";
```

then you can remove the loop. The result should look like  `... where pk IN ('1','2','3')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IN` keyword and pass your list by converting it to a comma seperated string in your query.

Something like

```
string Q = "select * from tablename where pk IN " + (comma seperated list here);
```