# LINQ aggregate query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to display a result from a database via via that includes an aggregate value from the same table.
i have a table that has Name, Score and Round which holds players names and scores for each particular round. I want to display that in a grid (say I select round 5) but I also want to show the rank of each player which is their total score over all rounds up to and including the selected round.

So far I have two queries - one returns a list of the the names and the sum of their round scores and another that retrieves their name, score for a particular round.
I only need the index of the sum though to get the rank, I don't need the sum of the score itself.
I'm trying to include the first query in the second query with something like

```
Rank = r1.FindIndex(r => r.Name == tr.Name)
```

but I keep getting the error 
'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 FindIndex'.
I know why I'm getting this (it can't be compiled into SQL) but I can't figure out how to get around it.
So, how can I structure my query so it gets the rows I need from the table but also factors in the correct rank i.e. index of a player in the first query?
Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you want queries to be run in-memory, use the `IEnumerable` form instead of the `IQueryable` form. The method to do this cleanly with Linq is [`.AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Rank = r1.AsEnumerable().FindIndex(r => r.Name == tr.Name);
```

Note that the call to `AsEnumerable()` is necessary ONLY if the compile-time type is `IQueryable`. Since we're talking about extension methods, they'll be called correctly based on the type known at runtime - and all the `IEnumerable` methods use a `foreach` and `yield return` pattern, which will iterate the SQL query into memory

Comment: Thanks for help but that line now says IEnumerable does not contain a definition for FindIndex.

Comment: This is because IEnumerable has no definition for FindIndex(). Maybe this can help you: [How to get the index of an element in an IEnumerable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290603/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-ienumerable) in case you follow Aravol's advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both Aravol and Flaudre. In the end a simply changed the data structure at the db end to hold the information I needed via a view. It was way simpler to implement than trying to figure these LINQ errors.