# Why IReadOnlyCollection has ElementAt but not IndexOf

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, readonly-collection

I am working with a `IReadOnlyCollection` of objects.

Now I'm a bit surprised, because I can use `linq` extension method `ElementAt()`. But I don't have access to `IndexOf()`.

This to me looks a bit illogical: I can get the element at a given position, but I cannot get the position of that very same element.

Is there a specific reason for it?

I've already read -> [How to get the index of an element in an IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290603/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-ienumerable) and I'm not totally happy with the response.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`IReadOnlyCollection` is a collection, not a list, so strictly speaking, it should not even have `ElementAt()`. This method is defined in `IEnumerable` as a convenience, and `IReadOnlyCollection` has it because it inherits it from `IEnumerable`. If you look at the source code, it checks whether the `IEnumerable` is in fact an `IList`, and if so it returns the element at the requested index, otherwise it proceeds to do a linear traversal of the `IEnumerable` until the requested index, which is inefficient.

So, you might ask why `IEnumerable` has an `ElementAt()` but not  `IndexOf()`, but I do not find this question very interesting, because it should not have either of these methods. An `IEnumerable` is not supposed to be indexable.

Now, a very interesting question is why `IReadOnlyList` has no `IndexOf()` either.

#### `IReadOnlyList<T>` has no `IndexOf()` ***for no good reason whatsoever***.

If you really want to find a reason to mention, then the reason is historical:

Back in the mid-nineties when C# was laid down, people had not quite started to realize the benefits of immutability and readonlyness, so the `IList<T>` interface that they baked into the language was, unfortunately, mutable.

The right thing would have been to come up with `IReadOnlyList<T>` as the base interface, and make `IList<T>` extend it, adding mutation methods only, but that's not what happened.

`IReadOnlyList<T>` was invented a considerable time after `IList<T>`, and by that time it was too late to redefine `IList<T>` and make it extend `IReadOnlyList<T>`.  So, `IReadOnlyList<T>` was built from scratch.

They could not make `IReadOnlyList<T>` extend `IList<T>`, because then it would have inherited the mutation methods, so they based it on `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` instead.  They added the `this[i]` indexer, but then they either forgot to add other methods like `IndexOf()`, or they intentionally omitted them since they can be implemented as extension methods, thus keeping the interface simpler. ***But they did not provide any such extension methods.***

So, here, is an extension method that adds `IndexOf()` to `IReadOnlyList<T>`:

```
using Collections = System.Collections.Generic;

    public static int IndexOf<T>( this Collections.IReadOnlyList<T> self, T elementToFind )
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach( T element in self )
        {
            if( Equals( element, elementToFind ) )
                return i;
            i++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Be aware of the fact that this extension method is not as powerful as a method built into the interface would be.  For example, if you are implementing a collection which expects an `IEqualityComparer<T>` as a construction (or otherwise separate) parameter, this extension method will be blissfully unaware of it, and this will of course lead to bugs. (Thanks to Grx70 for pointing this out in the comments.)

Comment: It always amuses me how answers on stackoverflow are trying to provide justification for why a certain API is in a certain way or another, as if the API is always right, as if it has been built with perfect wisdom, so some justification must always be there to be found and to be explained to the presumed novice who asked the question.

Comment: (Who is usually not a novice at all, and they are usually asking the question because they see there is a problem with the API, and pointing a problem by asking a question is always considered more polite than ranting about it, which is what I generally prefer to do.)

Comment: There are way to many .NET APIs that are messed up and overly complicated for historical reasons. I would love to see a clean cut with any following major release. Compatibility is nice, but not at the price of dragging along design errors from the 90s

Comment: I agree with the main proposal of this answer, that there's no good reason for the lack of `int IndexOf(T)` method on `IReadOnlyList<T>`. The proposed workaround however has a flaw in it, and I disagree with the statement that this method doesn't have to be included in the interface, because it can be "replaced" with an extension method. Imagine a collection that uses arbitrary `IEqualityComparer<T>`, and you might end up with this extension returning `-1` while `Contains(T)` returns `true` (or the other way around), which will likely lead into trouble.

Comment: @Grx70 I am not sure I understand what is the flaw that you detected.  Are you referring to the fact that my function is lacking an overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>`?  Are you referring to the fact that it does not appear to be making use of `IEquatable<T>`?  I could add those, but I think they are best left as an exercise to the reader.  Programmers who are advanced enough to make actual use of these interfaces would find that trivial.  Is there anything else?

Comment: @MikeNakis Let me give you an example. I actually stumbled upon this question while implementing custom ordered set (an `ISet<T>` that supports indexing, i.e. also implements `IReadOnlyList<T>`). Obviously, my class accepts arbitrary `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Let's say my class is internal, and so is the comparer I use, and I only expose it to you as `IReadOnlyList<T>` via dependency injection. Then it's impossible to write an extension method that would "always" return correct results, because you have no way of accessing the comparer, or even knowing that I use a custom one.

Comment: @MikeNakis My point is that `IReadOnlyList<T>` itself does not provide enough information to implement an extension method that would cover all possible scenarios. Sure, you can accept additional parameters, but that precisely illustrates that you need some additional information that `IReadOnlyList<T>` does not provide.

Comment: @Grx70 yes, I see.  I amended my answer to indicate the caveat that you are pointing out.  So what would be the solution to your situation?  I suppose you would have to expose `IList<T>` instead of `IReadOnlyList<T>` so that there is an `IndexOf()` in the interface which you can implement to make use of your `IEqualityComparer<T>`, right?

Comment: @MikeNakis I guess there isn't a single right way to approach this. You could either extend `IReadOnlyList<T>` to include `IndexOf(T)`, or implement `IList<T>` with `IsReadOnly` returning `true` and all mutating methods throwing an exception. My goal however was only to provide an argument for why `IndexOf(T)` **should** be part of `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: I missed this nuance the first time myself, but the original question was about `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, and not `IReadOnlyList<T>`. Lists extend collections, not the other way around, and a collection does indeed lack indexed access - by design, not by accident. This answer is probably accurate for read-only lists; it's illogical that they have indexed access but no `IndexOf`. However, it's not answering the same question. `IReadOnlyList<T>` is a much newer concept than `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` - I don't think the former even existed all the way back in 2016.

Comment: @Aaronaught yes, now that I am looking at it again, you are right. And it is not like the question has been edited. So I missed it too. I amended my answer.

Comment: Inheriting IList<T> from IReadOnlyList<T> would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle.  Imagine code that accepts two IReadOnlyList instances, but one happens to be a more-derived IList with mutation methods: while the method is iterating the immutable list, another thread is busily mutating the IList.  This is easy enough to avoid when you control all code paths, but what if you're consuming a library where the library authors have assumed the IReadOnlyList is immutable?

It's better to have a base class without mutation methods, then separately derive mutable and immutable versions.

Comment: @user1969177 You cannot assume that an interface is immutable. An interface can at best be "unmodifiable" or "readonly".  It is only a class that can be immutable.

Comment: @MikeNakis A class that implements derived-type IList<T> would be unsuitable for a parameter of type IReadOnlyList<T>, even if covariance rules allow it, simply because the parameter type implies a behavior that IList<T> contradicts.  Really the problem is the name, since you should not give a name to an interface for behavior it does not implement.  For example, you would be better to call the base interface an IList and its mutable, derived interface an IMutableList.  You could also derive IReadOnlyList from IList and override any mutation methods.

And give it IndexOf().

Comment: @user1969177: I disagree - "read only" is something very different from "immutable". If something is "read only", it means *you* cannot (directly) change it. It does not mean that it cannot change on its own. As such, assuming that an `IReadOnlyList` is immutable is simply an error.

Comment: Indeed, not all read-only lists are immutable, but to expect someone to make the distinction (or the author's intention) is a bit.. optimistic, at best.

Comment: @user1969177 The difference between read-only and immutable is not some obscure, esoteric distinction. Read-only is used to refer to mutable code elements all the time. In my experience MOST times you call something read-only you're talking about a mutable code element, not immutable. A BankAccount object likely has a read-only property called `Balance`, but no one in their right mind would think the `Balance` can never change just because it's read-only. Similarly, I would never assume an IReadOnlyList is immutable unless the documentation for a particular use of that type says it is.

Answer (score 4):

`IndexOf` is a method defined on `List`, whereas `IReadOnlyCollection` inherits just `IEnumerable`.

This is because `IEnumerable` is just for iterating entities. However an index doesn't apply to this concept, because the order is arbitrary and is not guaranteed to be identical between calls to `IEnumerable`. Furthermore the interface simply states that you can *iterate* a collection, whereas `List` states you can perform adding and removing also.

The `ElementAt` method sure does exactly this. However I won't use it as it reiterates the whole enumeration to find one single element. Better use `First` or just a list-based approach.

Anyway the API design seems odd to me as it allows an (inefficient) approach on getting an element at *n*-th position but does not allow to get the index of an arbitrary element which would be the same inefficient search leading to up to *n* iterations. I'd agree with Ian on either both (which I wouldn't recommend) or neither.

Comment: I totally agree with you with the fact that Enumerables are not meant to be accessed by index, but still I can use ElementAt(). To me it's a bit silly I get the element at a given position, but not the position of the element. It's more of a philosophical point :)

Comment: This is indeed a weird method. I assume it simply exists because anyone needed this future, however until now there wasn´t high demad towards an `IndexOf`-method.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the `IReadOnlyCollection` (which implements `IEnumerable`) does not necessarily implement `indexing`, which often required when you want to numerically order a `List`. `IndexOf` is from `IList`.

Think of a collection without index like `Dictionary` for example, there is no concept of numeric index in `Dictionary`. In `Dictionary`, the order is not guaranteed, only one to one relation between key and value. Thus, collection does not necessarily imply numeric indexing.

Another reason is because `IEnumerable` is not really two ways traffic. Think of it this way: `IEnumerable` may enumerate the items `x` times as you specify and find the element at `x` (that is, `ElementAt`), but it cannot efficiently know if any of its element is located in which index (that is, `IndexOf`).

But yes, it is still pretty weird even you think it this way as would expect it to have *either* both `ElementAt` and `IndexOf` *or* none.

Answer (score 3):

`IReadOnlyCollection<T>` has `ElementAt<T>()` because it is an extension to `IEnumerable<T>`, which has that method.  `ElementAt<T>()` iterates over the `IEnumerable<T>` a specified number of iterations and returns value as that position.

`IReadOnlyCollection<T>` lacks `IndexOf<T>()` because, as an `IEnumerable<T>`, it does not have any specified order and thus the concept of an index does not apply.  Nor does `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` add any concept of order.

I would recommend `IReadOnlyList<T>` when you want an indexable version of `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.  This allows you to correctly represent an unchangeable collection of objects with an index.

Comment: "Don't use it" isn't really an answer, but there is some value in what you say. Maybe you could make this look more like an answer by indicating that `ICollection<T>` doesn't have an `IndexOf()` method either, whereas `IList<T>` has. So it's merely a question of semantics, i.e. a collection is seen as an order-less bag (*probably*, but that's always the problem with these "why" questions: who knows?).

Comment: @GertArnold You're right.  I was relying on the user reading my comment last.  Now that you've pointed it out I can see the problem with that.  I will edit my answer to be more complete.

Comment: The main problem is that `IReadOnlyList<T>` *also* doesn't have an `IndexOf()` function implemented.  `IReadOnlyCollection` not having it isn't that big a deal, since it doesn't have indexing semantics, but the entire point of using a list is that it's supposed to be ordered and indexable. `List<T>` and `IList<T>` both have it, but `IReadOnlyList` does not.  It's rather frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

This extension method is almost the same as Mike's. The only difference is that it includes a predicate, so you can use it like this: `var index = list.IndexOf(obj => obj.Id == id)`

```
public static int IndexOf<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T> self, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < self.Count; i++)
    {
        if (predicate(self[i]))
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for contributing. Please look into Mike Nakis answer and consider if your answer is kind of a duplicate. If not please edit your answer and provide a little extra explanation and a code example calling your function, especially   concerning the predicate parameter. Thank you!

Comment: It's almost the same as Mike's. The only difference is it's using predicate, so you can use it like this: var index = list.IndexOf(obj => obj.Id == id)