# How to get item from IEnumerable collection using its index in C#?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have `IEnumerable` list of `customerList` and index. Now I want to get item of `IEnumerable` based on index.

For example, if `index = 3`, it should provide me 3rd item of the IEnumerable .

Please guide.

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customerList = new Customer[] 
{ 
     new Customer { Name = "test1", Id = 999 }, 
     new Customer { Name = "test2", Id = 915 }, 
     new Customer { Name = "test8", Id = 986 },
     new Customer { Name = "test9", Id = 988 },
     new Customer { Name = "test4", Id = 997 },
     new Customer { Name = "test5", Id = 920 },
};

int currentIndex = 3;   //want to get object Name = "test8", Id = 986
```

Comment: *Don't* use `IEnumerable<T>` here. Use `IList<T>`

Comment: You would have to do `customerList.ToList()[2];`. Remember that indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @Icemanind: `customerList.ToList()` may create an *enourmous* list (or even throw `OutOfMemory` exception) when we want just a *2-nd* item

Comment: @Icemanind there's no reason to use `ToList()` when the array is *already* an IList<T>. Just cast it to the correct type. Better yet, *don't* use `IEnumerable<T>` in the first place

Comment: I don't see how [_"How to get the index of an element in an IEnumerable"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290603/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-ienumerable) can be a duplicate of [_"How to get the item from an IEnumerable using its index"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120635/how-to-get-item-from-ienumerable-collection-using-its-index-in-c). That are two different things and the answers are also not related.

Comment: There is really something wrong with stackoverflow voting question, this question has right answer, if someone votes down no body know why ?? i often see voting down was because of some misunderstanding, or some time OP fix the problem but still it stays voted down that does not make sense.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> For example, if index = 3, it should provide me 3rd item of the
>   IEnumerable

You know that indexes are zero based in .NET? However, you can use [`ElementAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Customer c = customerList.ElementAt(currentIndex); // 4th
```

Use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) to prevent an exception if there are not enough items, then you get `null`:

```
Customer c = customerList.ElementAtOrDefault(currentIndex); // 4th or null
```

These methods are optimized in a way that they use the [`IList<T>` indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1.item?view=netframework-4.7.2). So in your example there is actually an `Customer[]` which implements that interface, hence it will use the indexer.

If the sequence does **not** implement `IList<T>` it will be enumerated to find the item at this index.

Comment: NB: `ElementAt` is an extension method provided by the `System.Linq` namespace.  I.e. you'll need to ensure you have a `using System.Linq;` statement in your code.

Comment: One should note that ElementAt might not be O(1).

Comment: @Aron: added it.

Answer (score 3):

*Don't* use IEnumerable if you want index-based access. Use [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead :

```
IList<Customer> customerList = new Customer[] 
{ 
    new Customer { Name = "test1", Id = 999 }, 
    new Customer { Name = "test2", Id = 915 }, 
    new Customer { Name = "test8", Id = 986 },
    new Customer { Name = "test9", Id = 988 },
    new Customer { Name = "test4", Id = 997 },
    new Customer { Name = "test5", Id = 920 },
};
```

With IEnumerable, the only option is to use the [ElementAt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netframework-4.7.2) extension method.

`IEnumerable<T>` guarantees only that a collection can be enumerated. It makes no other promises about accessing elements. ElementAt allows access to a specific element by *enumerating* that collection one item at a time until the required element is reached. That can be expensive.

Luckily, [ElementAt checks to see whether the argument is an IList](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,1231) and uses index-based access if possible.

That doesn't mean you should use `IEnumerable<T>` though. It will confuse maintainers (including you) that don't know what the actual instance behind the variable is. It will also cause performance issues if something that *isn't* an IList is ever assigned to that variable

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using `ElementAt` method.

If your IEnumerable is **not** a materialized collection, but a generated sequence, calling `ElementAt` method multiple times will cause the sequence to be generated multiple times. This is usually not desired, as it unnecessarily consumes resources.

Some of the answers above suggest using `IList` instead of `IEnumerable`. Yes, definitely it'll make accessing by index less cumbersome, but using `IList` has a nasty side effect it makes the collection mutable. I'd use `IReadOnlyList` instead.

```
IReadOnlyList<Customer> customerList = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer { Name = "test1", Id = 999 },
    new Customer { Name = "test2", Id = 915 },
    new Customer { Name = "test8", Id = 986 },
    new Customer { Name = "test9", Id = 988 },
    new Customer { Name = "test4", Id = 997 },
    new Customer { Name = "test5", Id = 920 },
};

int currentIndex = 3;   //want to get object Name = "test8", Id = 986

var result = customerList[currentIndex];
customerList.Add(new Customer()); // doesn't compile
customerList[currentIndex] = new Customer(); // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is a 'streaming' data type, so think of it like a stream instead of an array.

```
var yourCustomer = customerList.Skip(2).First()
```

However if you wanted a more array like syntax IList may be a better abstraction for your use case.

Comment: _"IEnumerable is a 'streaming' data type"_ No, that's not said anywhere. It's just the base interface of everything that is enumerable. Your implementation would just prevent optimizations and ensure that the sequence is enumerated

Comment: That's a bad idea. `IEnumerable` is *not* a streaming data type. Accessing elements is already available through `ElementAt` which does what the combination of `Skip.First` do *as a worst case scenario*. If the collection is actually an IList, `ElementAt` will use indexed access.

Comment: Note I say IEnumerable is a streaming type because the interface has one function, GetEnumerator.  GetEnumerator returns an IEnumerator that can only MoveNext and Reset.  Everything else is a static extension method.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerator-1?view=netframework-4.7.2